# How to change my button depends on product template on Shopify

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, shopify

Good Day,

I'm trying to change the button based on my product template on Shopify but it seems like its not working please check my code and test site below

Demo: https://strokes-test.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage

I make a control flow for the template object but its not working.

Code.liquid

```
<div
  id="ProductSection-{{ section.id }}"
  data-section-id="{{ section.id }}"
  data-section-type="product"
  data-enable-history-state="true"
  data-ajax-enabled="{{ settings.enable_ajax }}"
>
<form method="post" action="/cart/add" id="product_form_5928354152609" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate" data-product-form>
{% if product.variants.size == 1 %}<ul class="item-swatch color_swatch_Value"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants[0].id }}" />
{% else %}
<select class="hidden" name="id">{% for variant in product.variants %}<option value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>{% endfor %} class="product-form__variants no-js"</select>
{% endif %}
<ul class="item-swatch color_swatch_Value">  
{% for option in product.options %}
  {% if option == 'Shades' %}
    {% assign index = forloop.index0 %}
    {% assign colorlist = '' %}
    {% assign color = '' %}
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
      {% capture color %}
        {{ variant.options[index] }}
      {% endcapture %}
      {% unless colorlist contains color %}  
      {% assign text = color | handleize %}
      <li>
       <label value="{{ variant.id}}" style="{% if text == 'white' %}border: 1px solid #cbcbcb; {% endif %}background-color: {{ color | split: ' ' | last | handle }}; background-image: url({{ text | append: '.png' | file_url }});"></label>
        {% if variant.image != null %}
        <div class="hidden">
          <img src="{{ variant.image.src | product_img_url: 'grande' }}" alt="{{ text }}"/>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
        {% capture tempList %}
          {{ colorlist | append: color | append: ' ' }}
        {% endcapture %}
        {% assign colorlist = tempList %}
      {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
  {% if template.name == "product" %}
  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="add" class=" btn product-form__cart-submit btn--secondary-accent " aria-haspopup="dialog" data-add-to-cart/>  
  {% else %}
  <input type="submit" value="Choose Set" class=" btn product-form__cart-submit btn--secondary-accent " aria-haspopup="dialog" data-add-to-cart/ onclick="window.location='{{ product.url | within: collection }}';" />   
  {% endif %}
</div>
  </form>
{% unless product == empty %}
  <script type="application/json" id="ProductJson-{{ section.id }}">
    {{ product | json }}
  </script>
  <script type="application/json" id="ModelJson-{{ section.id }}">
    {{ product.media | where: 'media_type', 'model' | json }}
  </script>
{% endunless %}
```

Comment: I think you need to replace this line code `{% if template.name == "product" %}` with `{% if template.handle contains "product" %}` to check the current template.

Comment: its not working I also tried ```{% if page.template_suffix == 'product'  %}```

Comment: I think you try to get the template of product page, right?

Comment: the main purpose to add an ATC button when there is no variant on the product loop?https://prnt.sc/10mcroz

Comment: Actually  I have 2 templates product and product.bundle on the collection page  i want to show ATC button on product template and Choose set for product.bundle

Comment: I think you need to use custom tags on the products level and change the text based on product tags, and add links to a single products page. like `{% assign ATCText = 'add to cart' %}{% if product.tags contains 'bundle' %}{% assign ATCText = 'Choose Set' %}{ % endif %}`

Comment: Make sense I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

when on `product.liquid` template `template_suffix` is empty `""`.  when on `product.bundle.liquid`, `template_suffix` is `"bundle"`

```
  {% if product.template_suffix == "" %}
  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="add" class=" btn product-form__cart-submit btn--secondary-accent " aria-haspopup="dialog" data-add-to-cart/>  
  {% elsif product.template_suffix == "bundle" %}
  <input type="submit" value="Choose Set" class=" btn product-form__cart-submit btn--secondary-accent " aria-haspopup="dialog" data-add-to-cart onclick="window.location='{{ product.url | within: collection }}';" />   
  {% endif %}
```